# find_in_set and find_in_set unexpected result

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
USE mysql;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ShowUsers;
DELIMITER $

CREATE PROCEDURE `ShowUsers`(IN KnownUsers varchar(500), IN KnownHosts varchar(500))
BEGIN
  SELECT
    user,host
  FROM
    user
  WHERE 
    NOT FIND_IN_SET(host, KnownHosts)
  AND
    NOT FIND_IN_SET(user, KnownUsers)
  ORDER BY user, host ASC;
END $
DELIMITER ;
```

Example complete data to work with:

```
+-------------+-------------+
| user        | host        |
+-------------+-------------+
| knownuser1  | 192.168.1.5 |
| knownuser2  | 192.168.1.5 |
| unknownuser | 192.168.1.5 | # I want this result to show
| someuser1   | 192.168.1.6 |
| someuser2   | 192.168.1.6 |
| someuser3   | 192.168.1.6 |
| root        | localhost   |
+-------------+-------------+
```

I have marked the result I would want to show from running the procedure, basically the two IN parameters are known users, and known hosts those that should be have a user record on this database.

Calling the function like this

```
# users and hostnames(ips) to match for exclusion from results.
SET @Usernames = 'knownuser1,knownuser2';
SET @Hostnames = '192.168.1.5';

CALL ShowUsers(@Usernames, @Hostnames);
```

Expected Result:

```
+-------------+-------------+
| user        | host        |
+-------------+-------------+
| unknownuser | 192.168.1.5 | # I want this result to show
| someuser1   | 192.168.1.6 |
| someuser2   | 192.168.1.6 |
| someuser3   | 192.168.1.6 |
| root        | localhost   |
+-------------+-------------+
```

Actual Result:

```
+-------------+-------------+
| user        | host        |
+-------------+-------------+
| someuser1   | 192.168.1.6 |
| someuser2   | 192.168.1.6 |
| someuser3   | 192.168.1.6 |
| root        | localhost   |
+-------------+-------------+
```

Explanation (off this topic but I think I should clarify) The reason I want this procedure to work, I have a master server with multiple remote slaves, the slaves need to have access to the masters database which means they also have to have "root" access, they can create/reconfigure their own access credentials. The problem with this is if one of those servers were ever compromised it would leave open the chance to have a new user added with credentials to basically all of the database. Wide open and free to take.

I could lock the slaves out after initial configuration and manually open up the door, run an update and then lock it again which would be pretty laborious for the application and make the application virtually useless.

The idea I'm going with right now is to run this procedure via cron run script and check for unknown users/hosts and lock that slave server out of the database until I accept or reject the user from the main application.

Comment: You have mixed up the order of variables when you called the stored proc.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, i've fixed that, its till not working as I want it to, I have multiple users for a single IP address, when I add the ip address to the hostnames string as edited, all of the rows for that ip are removed from the results, when if my thinking is correct, all of them should be shown as there is no matching user.

Comment: updated the question, hopefully this better clarifies my intent now.

Comment: *...rows containing the ip address...* How can a row contain the ip address?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get the question. Pls provide sample data, sample parameters, actual results and expected results.

Comment: @forpas because the table in question is mysql.user which has amongst other columns user, host, password so when I ask for **host** a hostname (or as in this instance) an ip address is returned. I am updating with a psuedo dataset, bear with me.

Comment: You apparently want the record where the username is not in the list and the hostname equals with the list. So, remove the not from the 2nd condition.

Comment: The records I want to display as user:host are known:unknown unknown:unknown unknown:known I believe that the accepted anwer does this, il do some more testing by adding bogus user:hosts to the table and see what yeilds but with my current data of permitted user:host it seems to be working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The condition in the `WHERE` clause is:

```
NOT FIND_IN_SET(host, KnownHosts) AND NOT FIND_IN_SET(user, KnownUsers)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
NOT (FIND_IN_SET(host, KnownHosts) OR FIND_IN_SET(user, KnownUsers))
```

which means that you want to **exclude** the rows for which:
`host` is included in `KnownHosts` or `user` is included in `KnownUsers`.

So for your sample data, the row:

```
unknownuser | 192.168.1.5
```

will not be returned, because `host = '192.168.1.5'` and it **is included** in `KnownHosts` (= `'192.168.1.5'`).
Maybe change the logical operator to `OR`, if this is the logic that you want to apply:

```
NOT FIND_IN_SET(host, KnownHosts) OR NOT FIND_IN_SET(user, KnownUsers)
```

Comment: Okay, that clarifies why its not working, do you have a suggestion as to how I can make it work, I assumed that it would work the same as WHERE user != something AND host != anotherthing. But thats obviously not the case. I would prefer to not have to run the query multiple times looping an array within the script if possible.

Comment: Its doing as asked in that its removing matches from the results, but it also matches if user1 from host1 was also added to host2. That's not what I intended. I need to find a way to have user host pairs that i supply excluded from results, so if a user from host1 was created on host2 and i dont pass in that pair as known then they will show in the result. Is that making sense?

Comment: No, this is not clear. The code in my answer is based on the requirement, sample data and expected results as they are in your question. If there are other cases and conditions to be met then this is a totally different requirement.

Comment: Yes it seems that is the case. I am going to have to revise my question.

Comment: When you introduce new requirements in the question then you invalidated the answers you already got. This is not how it works. New requirements are new questions.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will revert my edit and ask a new question.