# Supply user host pairs to be excluded from mysql results

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mariadb

**Data to work with:**

```
+-------------+-------------+
| user        | host        |
+-------------+-------------+
| user1       | host1       | -
| user1       | ip1         | -
| user1       | host2       | *
| user2       | host2       | -
| user2       | ip2         | -
| unknown     | unknown     | +
| user1       | unknown     | +
| unknown     | host        | +
+-------------+-------------+
```

The symbol to the right of the table are:
 - do not show | + show as they are unknown | * because a user can only connect to one host, unless I had authorised it in which case I would supply the user host pair to the call also and it would not show.

Thats how I want things to work anyway.

This is where I am at with help from my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58251214/find-in-set-and-find-in-set-unexpected-result) and as there is now a further condition a new question needs asking.

**Current procedure**

```
USE mysql;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ShowUsers;
DELIMITER $

CREATE PROCEDURE `ShowUsers`(
  IN KnownUsers varchar(500),
  IN KnownHosts varchar(500)
)
BEGIN
  SELECT
    user,host
  FROM
    user
  WHERE 
    NOT FIND_IN_SET(host, KnownHosts)
  AND
    NOT FIND_IN_SET(user, KnownUsers)
  ORDER BY user, host ASC;
END $
DELIMITER ;
```

**Calling the procedure like this**

```
# known users and known hostnames or ips to match and exclude from results.
SET @Usernames = 'user1,user2';
SET @Hostnames = 'host1,host2,ip1,ip2'

CALL ShowUsers(@Usernames, @Hostnames);
```

**Intended Result:**

```
+-------------+-------------+
| user        | host        |
+-------------+-------------+
| user1       | host2       | *
| unknown     | unknown     | +
| user1       | unknown     | +
| unknown     | host        | +
+-------------+-------------+
```

I want to be able to supply multiple user:host pairs of (known legitimate credentials) and return results that do not match, so return only suspect/illegitimate credentials in the query results.

I have created a fiddle https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xb7dWXbkokHGbcPdzR7BUa/4 Hopefully you can see where I am going with this.

Comment: So, you want `user1` to match with `192.168.1.5` only, and `user2` to match with `192.168.1.6` only ? If yes, why wouldn't the second row (`user1, host1`) also show up in the output ?

Comment: It would with the supplied values here but the list is much longer with different data, I shortened the values for the question and user1 host1 and user1 host2 for simplicity they are not actual credentials. none of them are but a table could be build using the data and then call using these credentials. I suppose looking at it that way, the credentials actually dont matter, just that the two values in a row should be matched values supplied if the don't, that record is returned.

Comment: I am thinking something along the lines of JSON but mariadb doesnt support it properly, this would be a synch to complete, I could submit json with user:host as key:value pairs and solve the problem with a string split and a standard select if !=

Comment: You don't need JSON; look at `Field()` function to do one-to-one matching in two different comma separated string. I am still unclear about why user1 host1 and user2 host2 are not in the output; otherwise a solution is ready

Comment: they would be with the given data here. sorry I didnt correct the call to explain it. bear with me, I will update the question, I will show expected results and and adjust the sets to the correct data for the table given.

Comment: I have updated. I'm trying get across my intention and I seem to be failing miserably at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on whatever I could understand from your problem statement, you will need to use multiple string operations to satisfy your conditions (explanation in inline comments below):

**Query**

```
SELECT
  `user`,`host`
FROM
  tbl
WHERE 

 -- NOT condition to avoid returning one-to-one mapping between `user` and `host`
 -- If `user` exist in the @Usernames, and the position of the 
 -- `user` matches with the position of the `host` in the @Hostnames
 NOT ( 
       FIND_IN_SET(`user`, @Usernames) > 0
       -- Host and User are at same position in the lists
       AND FIND_IN_SET(`user`, @Usernames) = FIND_IN_SET(`host`, @Hostnames) 
     )

 AND 

 -- NOT condition to handle `host` at the end of @Hostnames list, where 
 -- there is no corresponding `user` mapped
 NOT ( 
      FIND_IN_SET(`host`, @Hostnames) > CHAR_LENGTH(@Usernames) 
                                        - CHAR_LENGTH(REPLACE(@Usernames, ',', '')) 
                                        + 1 
     );
```

**Result**

```
| user    | host    |
| ------- | ------- |
| user1   | host2   |
| unknown | unknown |
| user1   | unknown |
| unknown | host    |
```

[**View on DB Fiddle**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/f1Y8ZSEiK4sQYgUhPw2NTy/0)

**Caveat:** Above query will not work when there is no user in the `@Usernames` list. For brevity purpose, I avoided making the conditions more complex to handle that. Moreover, I doubt that in your practical use-case, you would have a situation where there are no user in the list.

Comment: Thank you, this looks to work. As I will be supplying the user host pairs I will just make sure that the positions are correct.

Comment: No, it fails when I add more users to the list. Not sure you understood which is my fault. The biggest issue I have is that I cannot get the point across which I had hoped my fiddle would manage but thats not the case. It seems Ive wasted a lot of peopled time with these questions.

Answer (score 0):

This construct works (but not efficiently for huge tables):

```
WHERE (user, host) NOT IN ( ('u1', 'h1'), ('u2', 'h2), ... )
```

For further discussion, see "row constructor".